# How to change to case of a column to Upper in HQL Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want to change a column from a table to uppercase before using like and filtering what is the keyword in HQL?

here's my query

```
SELECT abc
FROM ABC abc
WHERE abc.id = ?
And upper(abc.description) like '%?%'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

HQL supports the `upper()` function defined by the EJB 3.0 specification in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses. From the documentation:

> #### [14.10. Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)
>
> - ...
> - Any function or operator defined by EJB-QL 3.0: `substring()`, `trim()`,
>     `lower()`, `upper()`, `length()`, `locate()`,
>     `abs()`, `sqrt()`, `bit_length()`, `mod()`
> - ...

So the following should work:

```
from DomesticCat cat where upper(cat.name) like 'FRI%'
```

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [14.10. Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)
- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 4.6.16.1 "String Functions"

Comment: I had to remember that "ilike" is allowed! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I m writing a sample query in HQL:

```
session.createQuery(from Certificate where lower(assignedTo)=:userName)
    .setString("userName",username);
```

Assumptions: a table named `Certificate` exists with field `assignedTo`.
`session` is the Hibernate Session.